# Plot of undirected igraph shows gaps between edge and vertex on one end of edge

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Consider a plot of a very simple undirected graph produced with igraph.

```
library(igraph)

edges = matrix(c(1,2), nrow=1, ncol=2)
g = graph.edgelist(edges, directed=FALSE)
set.seed(42)
plot(g, edge.width=2, vertex.size=30, edge.color='black', main='')
```

There is a small gap between the edge and vertex 2, but not between the edge and
vertex 1. Is there a way of removing that gap?

The graph I am really working with is larger and edges are a lot
shorter. While the gap goes almost unnoticed in the above example, it is
confusing in my case.

Comment: This works for me fine for me. I do know that what you describe tends to happen if you try to plot in a non-square plotting area but I don't remember how you actually do that. Related, you could try my package `library("qgraph");qgraph(edges)` in which this behavior should not occur.

Comment: I see the problem under Windows.  The gap increases in size as the window is resized.  It is a very small gap in this case, but I do appreciate your efforts for perfection.  Could you use `layout()` (the `igraph` function) to return coordinates of vertices, then plot your own graph from scratch.  Plot edges first then vertices on top.

Comment: Might be a bug. Btw. if you resize the plot, then it is best to redraw it, because the rescaling might magnify rounding errors. It is best to report igraph bugs at https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in igraph, and it happens because igraph leaves some space there for the arrow-head, even if the arrow-head is not there. I will fix it in the next igraph version.

As a workaround, what you can do is plotting each edge twice, on top of each other. For this you need to make your graph directed and then use the `edge.arrow.mode` option to avoid the arrows. This works because only one end of the edge is modified by the arrow plotter. Somewhat stupid to plot your graphs this way, but I cannot find a better workaround for now. As I said, the new version (the one after 0.6.4) will not have this problem.

```
library(igraph)

# Zoom in on the critical region, although the gap always has the 
# same size, unless you make the plotting window bigger
g <- graph(c(1,2), directed=FALSE)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(g, edge.width=2, vertex.size=20, edge.color='black', main='',
     rescale=FALSE, xlim=c(0.9,1), ylim=c(0.9,1),
     layout=rbind(c(0,0), c(1,1)), vertex.color="#ffffff11")
```

[image: gap]

```
# This plot should have no gaps
g2 <- as.directed(g, mode="mutual")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(g2, edge.width=2, vertex.size=20, edge.color='black', main='',
     rescale=FALSE, xlim=c(0.9,1), ylim=c(0.9,1),
     layout=rbind(c(0,0), c(1,1)), vertex.color="#ffffff11",
     edge.arrow.mode="-")
```

[image: no gap]

Answer (score 1):

I read the `?igraph` page and saw a recommendation to use the 'good-looking anti-aliased Cairo device' [?igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/plot.common.html).

So, I tried

```
library(Cairo)
Cairo(1600, 1600, file="plot.png", type="png", bg="white")
plot(g, edge.width=2, vertex.size=30, edge.color='black', main='')
dev.off()
```

and,

```
CairoPDF("plot.pdf", 6, 6, bg="transparent")
plot(g, edge.width=2, vertex.size=30, edge.color='black', main='')
dev.off()
```

Both the png and pdf version look like there is no small *gap*.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't try it out, because I am actually using a [tikz](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/) device which also produces the gap.

Comment: @severin, and from what you write I assume you cannot use the solution above, but need to use the tikz-solution?

Comment: for some reason I missed your question last year. Sorry! Yes, unfortunately, I have to use the tikz device.

Comment: @severin, so did you solve the problem and are you still working to solve it?